# Get I/O TPS for NFS on Solaris machines

Tags: solaris, iostat

I'm attempting to get IOPS for my Solaris servers. Typically I use tps for this calculation, however:

iostat gives TPS but only for local disks.
iostat -x gives everything but TPS for ALL disks.
sar -d gives a lof...(but no TPS) for ALL disks.

Is there a way to get TPS/IOPS for NFS mounts on Solaris?

Answer (score 1):

For solaris 10 and 11.1 at least.

I believe iostat -xn gives you r/s and w/s which combined is the IOPS of the nfs resource:

```
        user@server:~$ iostat -xn 2 2
                    extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
   58.1    0.0 7196.9    0.0  0.0  0.1    0.4    2.2   0   5 somenfsserver:/share
    0.0   57.4    0.0 7340.6  6.7  0.6  116.0   10.8   4  10 anothernfsserver:/share1
                    extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
  747.3    0.0 95660.1    0.0  0.1  3.1    0.1    4.2   4  86 somenfsserver:/share
    0.0  748.3    0.0 95787.5 158.5 10.0  211.8   13.3 100 100 sanothernfsserver:/share1
```

r/s + w/s = IOPS, in this case I am reading from share and writing to share1.